# Rounding down dbl values in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)
```

This is what my code looks like, I'm getting my desired output. However, I'd like the temperature `temp` values to be rounded down. How can I achieve this?

It seems that my temp column is classified as `<dbl>`.

```
dep_delay_by_temp <- flights %>%
  inner_join(weather, by = c(
    "origin" = "origin",
    "year" = "year",
    "month" = "month",
    "day" = "day",
    "hour" = "hour"
  )) %>%
  group_by(temp) %>%
  summarise(avg_delay = mean(dep_delay, na.rm = TRUE))
dep_delay_by_temp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dep_delay_by_temp <- flights %>%
mutate(temp = floor(temp)) %>%
  inner_join(weather, by = c(
    "origin" = "origin",
    "year" = "year",
    "month" = "month",
    "day" = "day",
    "hour" = "hour"
  )) %>%
  group_by(temp) %>%
  summarise(avg_delay = mean(dep_delay, na.rm = TRUE))
dep_delay_by_temp
```